# Email Extension Plugin is not loading groovy template added via Config File Provider Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-email-ext

I am currently working on sending custom email notifications from jenkins build pipeline designed using declarative syntax.I have `Config File Provider Plugin 3.8.0, Email Extension Plugin 2.82 & Email Extension Template Plugin 1.2` installed on my jenkins server.

I have also done global system configurations(smtp creds, default values etc.) required for Email Extension Plugin to work.

Then I created a simple groovy template script and added it as managed file on Jenkins using Config File Provider Plugin with name *my-email-template*. While adding file I selected file type as *Extended Email Publisher Groovy Template*.

Then I added below steps in my Jenkinsfile,

```
steps {
  emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="managed:my-email-template"}''',
  mimeType: 'text/html',
  subject: "[Jenkins] ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
  to: "abc@gmail.com"    
}
```

Through above configurations I received a mail with body as;

> Groovy Template file [managed:my-email-template] was not found in
> $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates.

As per official [Email Extension Plugin documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/), I have used *managed:* prefix for my template file referrence, so I was expecting it to be referring to the managed file configured, but it's still searching the file under jenkins home.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: have you checked if replacing the declarative agent with the new plugin Pipeline:Declarative fixes the issue ?

Comment: Yes, I have Pipeline: Declarative v1.8.4 installed (it's the latest one) which is getting used by default.

Comment: @vsbehere does the solution I provided works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default email extension plugins looks inside ${JENKINS_HOME}/email-templates/ directory.
If you have a script named "my-email-template" and not using Config File Provider Plugin , then you would put your script in the **${JENKINS_HOME}/email-templates/** directory and use it in below way:

```
stage("Send Email")
   {
     steps {
                emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="my-email-template"}''', subject: 
                'Email subject  ', to: 'abc@gmail.com'
          }
   }
```

In case , the email extension plugin in unable to find the template file, then it will always give the error as below irrespective if you are working with managed plugins:

```
Groovy Template file [my-email-template.template] was not found in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates.
```

**Using Config File Provider Plugin and managed: prefix :**

Step 1 : Got to Manage Jenkins -> Managed Files 
Step 2 : Click -> Add a new config 
Step 3 : Select **Type** as **Extended Email Publisher Groovy Template** and click submit
Step 4 : Give Name of your file as your choice and add content of your template file.**Ensure you copy this name** as it will be used in the pipeline. Click on submit.

[image]

Step 5 : Add code in your pipeline. Ensure you put the correct Name **"managed:Groovy Email Template"**

```
stage("Send Email")
   {
     steps {
                emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="managed:Groovy Email Template"}''', subject: 
                'Email subject  ', to: 'abc@gmail.com'
          }
   }
```

The above should run and you can see the contents of the template file at below path :
 `${JENKINS_HOME}/org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles.xml`

**Note**:
If the above method does not work then please restart jenkins / reinstall the plugin email extension plugin, as done by vsbehere as the method is correct.

Comment: In your step 5, you mentioned ${SCRIPT, "managed:Groovy Email Template"}. Is it the correct way, because template= is missing before "managed:Groovy Email Template" ?

Comment: @vsbehere no sorry that was a typo from my end. I have used the same plugin version as mentioned by you and generated the output. It works fine.Can you please check if the template name that you mentioned is correct? and also is the contents of your file `${JENKINS_HOME}/org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles.xml` updated with the template content, and if you can run the same example as i have given

Comment: I checked ${JENKINS_HOME}/org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles.xml it has my groovy template content. I also reverified file name configured and used, both are same.

Comment: @vsbehere : Can you please run in the stage with contents  `stage("Send Email")
   {
     steps {
                emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="managed:Groovy Email Template"}''', subject: 
                'Email subject  ', to: 'abc@gmail.com'
          }
   }`

Comment: I tried running this, got Groovy Template file [managed:Groovy Email Template] was not found in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates.

Comment: Ok can you create a new configuration file using Config File Provider Plugin  with Type as Extended Email Publisher Groovy Template and give name as Groovy Email New. Create a test pipeline job with below code `pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Send Email")
                        {
                             steps {
                emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="managed:Groovy Email New"}''', subject: 'Email subject  ', to: 'abc@gmail.com'
                                   }
                        }
            }
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232626/discussion-between-altaf-and-vsbehere).

Comment: I just now reinstalled the email exension plugin, then restarted jenkins and then followed the procedure you mentioned from scratch. The email sending worked. IDK what exactly happened, may be I missed some step or some settings were cached and due to reinstall/restart its fixed.  Anyways, you saved my day, so thanks for that. I will accept the answer.